# Conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm still stuck on conditional probabilities/expectations given a sigma field. Everyone here has been extremely helpful, and I'm hoping someone can do this simple proof, using the definition of conditional expectation.

$E(E(X|\mathcal{G}))=E(X)$.

Comment: Who ever down voted this question should at least explain why. Mathstackexchange is meant to help others and have discussions. If you're to pompous to see that, then have fun in life!

Comment: 1. No, people downvoting something do not have the obligation to "at least explain why" (and if you think two minutes about it, you should understand why). 2. MSE is not meant to have discussions (please reread a presentation of the site to check this). 3. Since the identity you are after is indeed **a direct consequence of the definition** (usually stated just after the definition in the notes on the subject), readers of your question may wonder what is the question exactly. 4. The same remark applies to [your other recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1734688).

Comment: I understand that, but once a question is posted, it is hard to delete it. I tried to delete this question, but was not able to. I did recognize my questions were not challenging and rather trivial. I don't think people have an obligation to explain anything they do, obviously, but as a math enthusiast, it's discouraging for people who do need help to be indirectly told that their questions are not good. However, I do thank you for helping me with my other questions.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ satisfies $$\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_A\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]]=\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_AX] $$ for all $A\in\mathcal G$. Since $\Omega\in\mathcal G$ and $\mathsf 1_\Omega\equiv 1$, we have
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]] = \mathbb E[\mathsf 1_\Omega\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]] = \mathbb E[\mathsf 1_\Omega X] = \mathbb E[X].$$

Comment: The definition would be $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{1}_A X]$. You cannot use the conditional expectation property before defining it.

Comment: @ctNGUYEN Thanks, I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})$ satisfies $E(XZ)=E\left(E(X\mid\mathcal{G})Z\right)$ whenever $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Now use this with $Z=1$, which is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, as $Z^{-1}(A)\in\{\emptyset,\Omega\}\subset\mathcal{G}$, for any borel set $A$.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I prove the above assertion if I wanted to show, for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$, $\int_{G} E(X|\mathcal{G})dP$=$\int_{G} X dP$.

Comment: Same thing with $Z=\mathbf{1}_G$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as noted in the other answers, $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$ for any $\sigma$-algebra. However, I will try to spell out the calculation with more detail.

If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{G}$, then for any $A\in\mathcal{F}$, $E(\mathbf{1}_AE(X\mid \mathcal{F})=E(\mathbf{1}_AX)$. That's the definition of conditional expectation. Now we'll perform the calculation in the question.
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(E(X|\mathcal{F}))&=\int_\Omega E(X\mid\mathcal{F}) \ P(d\omega)\quad \text{ (by definition of expectation)}\\
&=E(\mathbf{1}_\Omega E(X\mid\mathcal{F})) \\
&=E(\mathbf{1}_\Omega X) \quad \text{ (by definition of conditional expectation since $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$)}\\
&=\int_\Omega X \ P(d\omega)\\
&=E(X).
\end{aligned}
$$

However, a simple example is always helpful.

**Example:**

Let $X$ be uniform on $\{-1,0,1\}$, and $\mathcal{F}=\big\{\emptyset,\{-1\},\{0,1\},\Omega\big\}.$ Let $\Omega=\Omega_{-1}\cup\Omega_0\cup\Omega_1$ such that $X(\omega_i)=i$ for $\omega_i\in\Omega_i$. Let $Y=E(X\mid\mathcal{F})$. Because $E(\mathbf{1}_AY)=E(\mathbf{1}_AX)$ for any $A\in\mathcal{F}$, we deduce that $Y(\omega)=-1$ for any $\omega\in\Omega_{-1}$ and $Y(\omega)=1/2$ for any $\omega\in\Omega_{0}\cup\Omega_{1}$ (a simple but instructive exercise).

Thus, somewhat trivially, $E(Y)=0=E(X)$. However, we'll just go ahead and compute $E(Y)$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(Y)&=\frac{1}{3}\left(Y(\omega_{-1})+Y(\omega_0)+Y(\omega_1)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left(-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=0
\end{aligned}
$$