# Conditional Expectation given X is measurable wrt to sigma field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $E(X|\mathcal{G})=X$. I don't understand this. Since $X$ is a random variable, it is measurable to any sub $\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$. Wouldn't the above equation always hold? When is $X$ NOT $\mathcal{G}$-measurable?

The proof for this is: for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$, $\int_{G} X dP = \int_{G} X dP$. I don't understand what $X$ being $\mathcal{G}$ measurable has to to with the proof.

Comment: FYI...the two integrals in your proof are exactly the same...is there some distinction?

Comment: That is where my question comes in: yes they are identical (or up to sets with measure zero), hence the equality BUT I wanted to know if $X$ being $\mathcal{G}$-measurable played a role on the left hand side of the equality.

Comment: No....I mean the notation is exactly the same...so its trivially true for any mathematical statment

Comment: Exactly. That's why I don't understand what is going on. I'm using Billingsly for the course, but this proof is from Resnick, A Probability Path.

Comment: sorry then...I'm confused as well...the "proof" looks like  $X=X$ to me.

Comment: @Bey It might help to come back to the two conditions defining $E(X\mid\mathcal G)$, then the meaning of the formula would become clear.

Comment: @Did ah, I see...I was taking the statement at face value...but if $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ and $X$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then we are effectively not conditioning at all, correct? Since by the $\mathcal{G}$-measurability of $X$, we have established the triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{G},P)$ as an underlying probability space for $X$ and $E(X|\mathcal{G})$...then, since we are using the same set function $X(\omega): \Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ the two must give the same value for each $\omega$, correct? There's no missing sets where the two have different subsets for a given outcome.

Comment: @Bey Your formulations are dangerously ambiguous. First, every random variable involved, say $X$ and $E(X\mid\mathcal G)$, is defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Second the identity $X=E(X\mid\mathcal G)$, valid when $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, holds only almost surely and not pointwise since conditional expectations are defined indirectly by two conditions invariant by modifications on null sets (at least when $\mathcal G$ is complete). Say, would you be able to state the two conditions I am alluding to? If not, your first task should be to learn them...

Comment: @Did...I was using the same definition that John Dawkins used in their post...I was trying to say what they said ... It looked like they were the same object up to some null sets.

Comment: @Bey Appending `...` to `@user` with no intermediate space inactivates the signalment of the comment to user `user`. Re the maths, I am not sure you "followed" any other post, anyway my comment describes the proper setting to understand the question.

Comment: @Did thx, didn't realize that ellipsis messes with the system. The definition  of conditional expectation that I found was the one cited by John Dawkins below. My notation is not clear, but I was grasping at the idea that by $X$ being $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, we are really just re-defining the conditional expectation...my inexperience with measure theory left me unable to rigorously (or really coherently...) express this mathematically. Anyway, I didn't post an answer since this is an area I am just venturing into  myself...but I was interested in the question

Answer (score 6):

The conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal G)$ is a random variable determined (up to sets of probability $0$) by two properties: (i) $E(X|\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, and (ii) for each $\mathcal G$-measurable set $B$, the integral of $E(X|\mathcal G)$ over $B$ is equal to the integral of $X$ over $B$. If $X$ is itself $\mathcal G$-measurable, then it has these two properties, and so it must be $E(X|\mathcal G)$.

Answer (score 5):

$X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable if and only if for any borel set $A$, the event $\{X\in A\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{G}$.

Now if $X$ is a random variable, $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, by definition, so that $\{X\in A\}\in\mathcal{F}$. But if $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$, you can have $\{X\in A\}\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\{X\in A\}\not\in\mathcal{G}$.

For example, consider $X$ a Bernoulli random variable, with parameter $p\in(0,1)$ and $\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. Then $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $X$ is NOT $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Indeed, $X^{-1}(\{0\})\neq\emptyset$ and $X^{-1}(\{0\})\neq\Omega$.

More generally, the smaller the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, the harder it is to be measurable.

Comment: Ah! That's where my confusion was: I assumed all $\lbrace X \in A \rbrace$ belonged to all sub $\sigma$-fields. Thank you, times a million! I always get stuck on basic, or trivial, questions.

Comment: One question: when $\lbrace X \in A \rbrace \in \mathcal {G}$, does this imply that $\int_{G} X dP$ is defined for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$?

Comment: It's defined even if $X$ is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. As long as $X$ is a random variable and $G\in\mathcal{F}$, $\int_GXdP$ is well defined.

Comment: Okay. So my question is, why can't I just have $E(X|\mathcal{G})=X$ all the time. I edited my question to include the proof, which would then appear to hold all the time.

Comment: The conditional expectation must be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, by definition.  So if $X$ is not, the equality does not hold. Take the example of my answer. You have $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})=E(X)=p\neq X$.

Answer (score 2):

If X is $\mathcal{G}$  measurable then $\mathcal{G}$  has all the information about X.
If we condition the expected value of X on something which gives us all the information about X, then the expected value of X is going to be X itself.

E[X|X] = X; we already know X so that's what we expect. Also note that $E[X|X] $ is shorthand for $E[X|\sigma(X)] $

To justify why $\mathcal{G}$  has all the information about X.

Let ($\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$ , $\mathbb{P}$) be a probability space and let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable

By definition if X is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable then for any set $B \in Bor(\mathbb{R})$, $ X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{G}$.

That means that every interval in $\mathbb{R}$, representing any possible outcome for $X$, is mapped to an event in $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: I don't see how this answer adds anything new to the already existing answers?

Comment: I think it helps remember this in a more intuitive way